# Does it mean he has no doubt about it?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "I **would not dare** to say that there is a direct link between mathematics and madness, but there is no doubt that great mathematicians suffer from maniacal characteristics, delirium and symptoms of schizophrenia." 
>        <sub>*John F Nash*</sub>

What is the meaning of *would not dare to say* here?

Comment: Did your English language dictionary tell you anything about the verb _to dare_? What English dictionary do you consult? If you tell us how that dictionary entry fails to inform you of its meaning here, we can provide a more useful answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nash is comparing two statements: (a) there is a direct link between mathematics and madness; and (b) great mathematicians suffer from maniacal characteristics, delirium and symptoms of schizophrenia.

There is no doubt about (b). But there is some doubt about (a). Therefore he would need to be daring (brave) to assert (a); the assertion would expose him to the risk error. He is not sure enough of (a) to assert it; he is not daring enough to assert (a) given his level of certainty.

So he would not dare to say it, i.e. take the risky step of saying it.